# Surjectivity of p-adic representation

Tags: elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. For a prime $p$, we have the mod $p$ representation
\begin{equation*}
\bar{\rho}_{E,p}: G_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow Aut(E[p])
\end{equation*} and the $p$-adic representation 
\begin{equation*}
\rho_{E,p}: G_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow Aut(T_pE)
\end{equation*} where $T_pE$ is the p-adic Tate module.

We know that by Serre, 1972, that if $E$ has good reduction at $p$, and $p\geq 5$, then $\bar{\rho}_{E,p}$ is surjective if and only if $\rho_{E,p}$ is surjective. However, I have seen cases where it is stated that as long as $p\geq 5$, then this relation holds, without any conditions on the reduction at $p$ of E. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a more general version of this implication, with a detailed proof, in the first few pages of Swinnerton-Dyer's article in the Antwerp III proceedings (Springer Lecture Notes vol. 331). Swinnerton-Dyer certainly does not make any assumptions on the reduction type at $p$.